# How to get the authenticated user in spring boot when authentication is externalized (azure)

Tags: azure, spring-security, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

If I deploy a spring boot application as a azure app, I can externalize the authentication by

1. using azure API management and configuring oauth2 etc
2. using the authentication options of azure app service.
   As such I don't need to configure any authentication in my spring boot application.

All that works fine and I can find a lot of info about that. What I cannot find is: how do I retrieve the logged on user in my application in such case? How is that information passed to my application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oauth2 you should be able to fetch the username from JWT token/via an api call. You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56225056/8804776) which tells you how to read jwt token. Once you have the username then you can add it to a custom header and pass to your backend application. Follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader) to understand how to add custom header to your request in api manager to be passed to your back end